# How to create widget in lib folder in Android flutter

Tags: android, flutter, widget, ide, lib

How to create widget in lib folder in Android flutter

I wanted to create a widget inside lib folder in flutter Android IDE but it only creates file.

Comment: You can create a custom widget by defining it in a separate file. Once you've created it, you can use it in your widget tree for a more elegant and readable code structure.

If you need further help please don't hesitate to comment.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.